# Error FacebookAuthService GRAILS: json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter:

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a test application with the Facebook Authentication for Spring Security plugin. In this application, I want to obtain more details of Facebook, as for example: full name and email. I did the steps of a Internet tutorial but when I accept the Facebook request (next the application should save the new user), the error appears and redirects to login view of Spring Security Core (auth.gsp) and the new user doesn't save.

My User domain class is (I only copy the first part):

```
class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
String name
String email
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

User(String username, String password) {
    //this()
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
}
..... (continue)
```

FacebookUser domain class:

```
class FacebookUser {

Long uid
String accessToken
Date accessTokenExpires

static belongsTo = [user: User]

static constraints = {
    uid unique: true
}
}
```

Config.groovy file:

```
 // Facebook Authentication for Spring Security settings
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='facebook.FacebookUser'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.appId='xxxx'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.secret='xxxx'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.filter.redirect.failureHandler='redirectFailureHandler'`
```

FacebookAuthService.groovy:

```
 import grails.transaction.Transactional
 import facebook.FacebookUser
 import security.*
 import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
 import org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl
 import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook
 import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.FacebookProfile
 import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate
 import com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.FacebookAuthToken
 import javax.naming.AuthenticationException

 @Transactional
 class FacebookAuthService {

void onCreate(FacebookUser user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
    log.info("Creating user: $user for fb user: $token.uid")
}

void afterCreate(FacebookUser user, FacebookAuthToken token) {
    log.info("User created: $user for fb user: $token.uid")
}

Map onJsonSuccess(Map input, FacebookAuthToken token) {
    input['demo'] = 'An message from FacebookAuthService'
    return input
}

Map onJsonFailure(Map input, AuthenticationException exception) {
    StackTraceElement stack = exception.stackTrace.last()
    input['stacktrace'] = [
        line: stack.lineNumber,
        classname: stack.className
    ]
    return input
}

/**
 * Called when we have a new facebook user, called on first login to create all required
 * data structures. Replaces .createAppUser and .createRoles methods.
 *
 * @param token facebook authentication token
 */
FacebookUser create(FacebookAuthToken token) {
    log.info("Create domain for facebook user $token.uid")

    //Use Spring Social Facebook to load details for current user from Facebook API
    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(token.accessToken.accessToken)
    FacebookProfile fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
    String email = fbProfile.email
    String username = fbProfile.username
    String firstName = fbProfile.firstName
    String lastName = fbProfile.lastName

    User person = new User(
        username: username,
        password: token.accessToken.accessToken, //not really necessary
        enabled: true,
        accountExpired:  false,
        accountLocked: false,
        passwordExpired: false,

        //fill with data loaded from Facebook API
        name: [firstName, lastName].join(' '),
        email: email
    )
    person.save()
    //UserRole.create(person, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'))
    UserRole.create(person, Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_FACEBOOK'))
    FacebookUser fbUser = new FacebookUser(
        uid: token.uid,
        accessToken: token.accessToken.accessToken,
        accessTokenExpires: token.accessToken.expireAt,
        user: person
    )
    fbUser.save()
    return fbUser
}
```

And the error when I accept the request of Facebook login is:

```
|Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/FacebookAuth
| Error 2015-11-08 20:32:10,071 [http-bio-8080-exec-8]
ERROR [/FacebookAuth].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet
[default] in context with path [/FacebookAuth] threw exception [Filter
execution threw an exception] with root cause

Message:
org.springframework.http.converter.json.
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter
Line | Method
->>  381 findClass      in java.net.URLClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
424   loadClass                 in java.lang.ClassLoader
2701  privateGetDeclaredMethods in java.lang.Class 
1975  getDeclaredMethods        in     ''
49    getLocked . . . . .     in org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference
36    get                       in     ''
49    getLocked . . . . . . . . in     ''
36    get                       in     ''
49    getLocked . . . . . . . . in     ''
36    get                       in     ''
49    getLocked . . . . . . . . in     ''
36    get                       in     ''
49    $tt__create . . . . . . . in facebookauth.FacebookAuthService
113   create        in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.
DefaultFacebookAuthDao
72    authenticate . . in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.facebook.
FacebookAuthProvider
60    attemptAuthentication  in com.the6hours.grails.springsecurity.
facebook.FacebookAuthRedirectFilter
47    doFilter ..........       in     ''
62    doFilter    in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.
logout.MutableLogoutFilter
1142  runWorker . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
617   run         in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
745   run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: looks like it happens on line `String email = fbProfile.email`. Which versions of Grails, Jackson and Spring Social Facebook do you use?

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for replying me. Versions: Grails - 2.5.2, springSecurityCore - 2.0-RC5, springSecurityFacebook - 0.17. At first, I didn't put any Jackson dependency. Now I put in "Dependencies" in "BuildConfig": compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.3' but the problem continues with the same error. Besides, If I comment the email field, the error is the same. So, I think that it's a problem of the email field.

Comment: hm, i thought line 49 is for email (but yes, it looks strange, nothing wrong with this line). also it's possible that grails cannot find `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` class

Comment: And what is the solution? Because I didn't find any solution on the internet. Must I put the Jackson dependency in "BuildConfig"? Thanks

Comment: right now we're trying to find a cause of the error, after that we could find a solution for the problem

Comment: i mean, check that class exists, or not, or why it required there, maybe there are a conflict, etc

Comment: Ok, I thanks you that you can comment the solution after finding it.